# Pycaret error : TypeError: format() got an unexpected keyword argument 'precision'

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, pycaret

I'm using the compare_models() function for the classification problem in pycaret. It was running well during the process but in the end, it does not print anything but an empty list.

```
clf1 = setup(data = train_titanic_df, target = 'Survived')
compare_models(include = ['lightgbm', 'xgboost'], errors="raise")
```

After I adding *errors="raise"* to *compare_models()*, it gives me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[26], line 1
----> 1 compare_models(include = ['lightgbm', 'xgboost'], errors="raise") #'rf', 'ada','catboost'

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycaret/utils/generic.py:965, in check_if_global_is_not_none.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    963     if globals_d[name] is None:
    964         raise ValueError(message)
--> 965 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycaret/classification/functional.py:822, in compare_models(include, exclude, fold, round, cross_validation, sort, n_select, budget_time, turbo, errors, fit_kwargs, groups, experiment_custom_tags, probability_threshold, engine, verbose, parallel)
    680 @check_if_global_is_not_none(globals(), _CURRENT_EXPERIMENT_DECORATOR_DICT)
    681 def compare_models(
    682     include: Optional[List[Union[str, Any]]] = None,
   (...)
    698     parallel: Optional[ParallelBackend] = None,
    699 ) -> Union[Any, List[Any]]:
    700     """
    701     This function trains and evaluates performance of all estimators available in the
    702     model library using cross validation. The output of this function is a score grid
   (...)
    819     - No models are logged in ``MLFlow`` when ``cross_validation`` parameter is False.
    820     """
--> 822     return _CURRENT_EXPERIMENT.compare_models(
    823         include=include,
    824         exclude=exclude,
    825         fold=fold,
    826         round=round,
    827         cross_validation=cross_validation,
    828         sort=sort,
    829         n_select=n_select,
    830         budget_time=budget_time,
    831         turbo=turbo,
    832         errors=errors,
    833         fit_kwargs=fit_kwargs,
    834         groups=groups,
    835         experiment_custom_tags=experiment_custom_tags,
    836         probability_threshold=probability_threshold,
    837         engine=engine,
    838         verbose=verbose,
    839         parallel=parallel,
    840     )

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycaret/classification/oop.py:1190, in ClassificationExperiment.compare_models(self, include, exclude, fold, round, cross_validation, sort, n_select, budget_time, turbo, errors, fit_kwargs, groups, experiment_custom_tags, probability_threshold, engine, verbose, parallel)
   1187         self._set_engine(estimator=estimator, engine=eng, severity="error")
   1189 try:
-> 1190     return_values = super().compare_models(
   1191         include=include,
   1192         exclude=exclude,
   1193         fold=fold,
   1194         round=round,
   1195         cross_validation=cross_validation,
   1196         sort=sort,
   1197         n_select=n_select,
   1198         budget_time=budget_time,
   1199         turbo=turbo,
   1200         errors=errors,
   1201         fit_kwargs=fit_kwargs,
   1202         groups=groups,
   1203         experiment_custom_tags=experiment_custom_tags,
   1204         verbose=verbose,
   1205         probability_threshold=probability_threshold,
   1206         parallel=parallel,
   1207         caller_params=caller_params,
   1208     )
   1209 finally:
   1210     if engine is not None:
   1211         # Reset the models back to the default engines

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycaret/internal/pycaret_experiment/supervised_experiment.py:788, in _SupervisedExperiment.compare_models(self, include, exclude, fold, round, cross_validation, sort, n_select, budget_time, turbo, errors, fit_kwargs, groups, experiment_custom_tags, probability_threshold, verbose, parallel, caller_params)
    786 results_columns_to_ignore = ["Object", "runtime", "cutoff"]
    787 if errors == "raise":
--> 788     model, model_fit_time = self._create_model(**create_model_args)
    789     model_results = self.pull(pop=True)
    790 else:

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycaret/internal/pycaret_experiment/supervised_experiment.py:1575, in _SupervisedExperiment._create_model(self, estimator, fold, round, cross_validation, predict, fit_kwargs, groups, refit, probability_threshold, experiment_custom_tags, verbose, system, add_to_model_list, X_train_data, y_train_data, metrics, display, model_only, return_train_score, **kwargs)
   1570     self._master_model_container.append(
   1571         {"model": model, "scores": model_results, "cv": cv}
   1572     )
   1574 # yellow the mean
-> 1575 model_results = self._highlight_and_round_model_results(
   1576     model_results, return_train_score, round
   1577 )
   1578 if system:
   1579     display.display(model_results)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycaret/internal/pycaret_experiment/supervised_experiment.py:1266, in _SupervisedExperiment._highlight_and_round_model_results(self, model_results, return_train_score, round)
   1264     indices = ["Mean"]
   1265 model_results = color_df(model_results, "yellow", indices, axis=1)
-> 1266 model_results = model_results.format(precision=round)
   1267 return model_results

TypeError: format() got an unexpected keyword argument 'precision'
```

what I tried so far:

1- Upgrade pycaret to version `3.0.0.rc9`.

2- Trying other model other than lightgbm and xgboost.

3- Check my python version which is 3.8.5.

I searched online a lot but couldn't find anything that address this error! I appreciate any help with this error.

Comment: So it is `'{}'.format(value_to_be_passed)`

Comment: Sorry, could you explain where should I add this ```'{}'.format(value_to_be_passed)```?

Comment: Can you try the latest PyCaret (PyCaret 3.0.2)? I can run the compare_models() with both "lightgbm" and "xgboost" and errors="raise" argument without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the latest version of pycaret (3.0.2 as of the writing of this answer) to see if it resolves the issue.